# How to manage views,urls and models on large scale in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am new to the Django. i was going through so many Django tutorials but in all tutorials they were managing all views and model in same files as named views and model. there is any standard way so it can be properly manageable.

**It is possible to mange call views, urls and model using database ?**

**How to manage this things on enterprise level.**

Comment: You can break your app into smaller apps, so each app will have its individual views / URLs / models.

Comment: @Stack but when number of views, urls and models increases it is really hard to mange even after small apps

Comment: You can create a package called views. Then you can create a separated file for each view and import each one of them into __init__.py of views package. Doing that you are still able to import views as previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a package called **views**. Then you can create a separate file for each view and import each one of them into __init__.py of views package. Doing that you are still able to import views as previously.

```
my_app.
├── views
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── my_view.py
```

Then in my_view.py:

```
def my_view(request):
    pass
```

And in the __init__.py:

```
from my_app.views.my_view import my_view
```

In all other files, you can import my_view like this:

```
from my_app.views import my_view
```

The same can be done for models, URLs, ...

Answer (score 2):

In my experience in different projects and teams, we did it in this way:

```
application
├── api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── v1
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── view_a.py
│       ├── ...
│       ├── view_z.py
│       └── urls.py
├── apps.py
...
```

I keep my views in different versions, so we can support backward compatibilities in APIs and Views.
You have to create a **Python Package** (a directory including an `__init__` file); And just import everything you want to export from that package.

For example, in `application/api/v1/__init__.py`:

```py
from .view_a import FooListView
from .view_b import BarDetailView
```

And, of course, you can create classes inside the `__init__` file too. Everything you write in it is accessible from the Package's name directly instead of the views' file name.

Don't forget to keep versioning your APIs in `urls.py` too.

```py
# api/urls.py
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/', include('application.api.v1.urls')),
    path('v2/', include('application.api.v2.urls')),
    ...
]
```

```py
# api/v1/urls.py
from django.urls import path

from . import *  # this imports every view classes from __init__.py file
                 # Or you can just import directly from views instead
                 # of having an __init__ file:
                 # from .view_a import FooListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/', FooListView.as_view()),
    ...
]
```